# Timer cancel() synchronization

Tags: java, timer, synchronous

I'm looking for a way to synchronize the cancel() method.
The expected result is the first() method is guaranteed to be called first.

```
 timer = new Timer();
 timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Simulation of a long task.
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch(Exception e){
        }
            first();
    }
 }, delayNoMatter, veryShortInterval);
}

void first() {
    System.out.println("first");
}

void second() {
//This method must be called last.
    System.out.println("second");
}

void print() {
    timer.cancel();
    second();
}
```

```
Expected result:
...
first 
second
```

I tried to use an empty synchronization block, but there is an opinion that it is not desirable to use empty blocks.

```
timer = new Timer();
 timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    synchronized(o){
        try {
            //Simulation of a long task.
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch(Exception e){
        }
            first();
    }}
 }, delayNoMatter, veryShortInterval);
}

void first() {
    System.out.println("first");
}

void second() {
//This method must be called last.
    System.out.println("second");
}

void print() {
    timer.cancel();
    //I'm not sure how correct this solution is. There is an opinion that using 
    //empty blocks is a bad way.
    synchronyzed(o)
    second();
}
```

Comment: This is a bad use of threading.  To execute methods in a given order, use a single thread: `first(); second();` just like that where you have the `first()` method call.  Can you give more information on exactly what you are trying to do?  I think your example is a bit too simple for us to understand what the real issue might be.

Comment: And if you want `first()` called first, then I don't understand that `print()` cancels the thread.  What is the real use of this method?

Comment: All method names are taken arbitrarily, as a simpler example. The point is to ensure that Timer.cancel() is executed synchronously so that run() is not called after.

Comment: Simply put, I need a guarantee that after calling cancel () there will be no more  run () calls. (I'm sorry if this is a bad example. My first post)

Comment: Don't apologize. Instead, [edit] and clarify your question, adding all pertinent information in the question and not just in comments down here.

Comment: Actually there is nothing to clarify. I laid it out as simply as I could.

Comment: Why would the synchronized block accomplish anything? Who else is synchronizing on `this` that it's waiting for?

Comment: Even if you put the whole `run()` is a synchronized block, there's no guarantee your empty block gets hit second.

Answer (score 0):

The `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes were supplanted by the Executors framework added to Java 5. This fact is noted in the Javadoc for those classes.

An [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) object will process one or more tasks in one or more background threads.

You seem to have two goals in mind.

- Run a series of tasks in order.
- Halt the processing of further tasks upon some flag.

Both can be accomplished with an executor service.

For the first, use a single-threaded executor service. With only a single thread at its disposable, the executor service schedules each task to run one after another, in the order in which they were submitted.

For the second, I would signal a flag via an `AtomicBoolean` object, with your tasks written to look for them. With a single instance of `AtomicBoolean`, initialized before you set up your executor service, then reading and writing to the contained boolean value is [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

Let's take an example task that loops a few times, pretending each time to do some work which we simulate by sleeping the thread.

```java
package work.basil.example.vthreads;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class SeriesOfTasks
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        SeriesOfTasks app = new SeriesOfTasks ( );
        app.demo ( );
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        System.out.println ( "INFO - Demo starting. " + Instant.now ( ) );
        final AtomicBoolean keepGoingFlag = new AtomicBoolean ( true );
        try (
                ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor ( ) ;
        )
        {
            executorService.submit ( new TellTime ( "A" , keepGoingFlag ) );
            executorService.submit ( new TellTime ( "B" , keepGoingFlag ) );
            executorService.submit ( new TellTime ( "C" , keepGoingFlag ) );
            try { Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofSeconds ( 20 ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
            keepGoingFlag.set ( false );
            executorService.submit ( new TellTime ( "D" , keepGoingFlag ) );
        }
        System.out.println ( "INFO - Demo ending. " + Instant.now ( ) );
    }
}

class TellTime implements Runnable
{
    private final String id;
    private final AtomicBoolean continueFlag;

    public TellTime ( final String id , final AtomicBoolean continueFlag )
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.continueFlag = continueFlag;
    }

    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        for ( int ordinal = 1 ; ordinal <= 3 ; ordinal++ )
        {
            if ( this.continueFlag.get ( ) )
            {
                int seconds = ThreadLocalRandom.current ( ).nextInt ( 1 , 3 );
                try { Thread.sleep ( Duration.ofSeconds ( seconds ) ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { throw new RuntimeException ( e ); }
                System.out.println ( "Task " + this.id + " ordinal " + ordinal + " in thread id " + Thread.currentThread ( ).threadId ( ) + " says the time is " + Instant.now ( ) );
            } else
            {
                System.out.println ( "Task " + this.id + " ordinal " + ordinal + " in thread id " + Thread.currentThread ( ).threadId ( ) + " found the flag set to FALSE at " + Instant.now ( ) );
                break;   // Else exit this loop.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When run:

```
INFO - Demo starting. 2023-09-07T23:01:10.086790Z
Task A ordinal 1 in thread id 21 says the time is 2023-09-07T23:01:11.167055Z
Task A ordinal 2 in thread id 21 says the time is 2023-09-07T23:01:13.229073Z
Task A ordinal 3 in thread id 21 says the time is 2023-09-07T23:01:15.303675Z
Task B ordinal 1 in thread id 21 says the time is 2023-09-07T23:01:16.579288Z
Task B ordinal 2 in thread id 21 says the time is 2023-09-07T23:01:17.640376Z
Task B ordinal 3 in thread id 21 says the time is 2023-09-07T23:01:19.712922Z
Task C ordinal 1 in thread id 21 says the time is 2023-09-07T23:01:21.741175Z
Task C ordinal 2 in thread id 21 says the time is 2023-09-07T23:01:23.813196Z
Task C ordinal 3 in thread id 21 says the time is 2023-09-07T23:01:24.818768Z
Task D ordinal 1 in thread id 21 found the flag set to FALSE at 2023-09-07T23:01:30.169407Z
INFO - Demo ending. 2023-09-07T23:01:30.176363Z
```

In that code we use try-with-resources syntax to automatically shutdown the executor service after all submitted tasks are done. If you want to stop the executor service from accepting more tasks, call `shutdown`. If you want to halt submitted tasks, call `shutdownNow` and write your task classes to be aware of possible interruption.